# Where to hook to bypass instantiating WP_Query?

Tags: rewrite-rules

I'm a bit stalled in a plugin creation, as I do not find a way to elegantly hook things up.

A strip down version of my problem is the following:

1. Boot Wordpress completely (core and plugins)
2. Detect certain URL patterns like mydomain.com/video/video_id
3. In this case call a function is_404(video_id) in my plugin

   1. If true, then I want to
      jump directly to loading the usual 404 template
   2. If false, then I
      call a template file template_directory/my_video.php?v=video_id (I
      won't need the_loop)

I've found the rewrite hooks, but I don't see how to make them work since I don't need to instantiate WP_Query. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here. I'd recommend showing any code you're already using that's not working and describing your problem in terms of expected outcome/actual outcome. Also, are you sure you're asking about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to get rid of `WP_Query` in WP load process it's pretty horribly inconvenient to accomplish. :)

Let's recap the process as related to rewrite:

1. Web server takes pretty permalink and rewrites it to WP's `index.php`.
2. WP takes "pretty" part and applies its rewrite rules to it, turning it into query variables.
3. Query variables are processed and fed into a `WP_Query`.
4. Depending on results of query vars and retrieved posts conditionals are set up.
5. Conditionals are used to determine template.
6. Template is used to display posts, if any.

So it is a little hard to understand from your description how do you need to integrate your things into this.

The most extensive scale would be to register your own query variables, your own rewrite rules, and make use of that data in `WP_Query`.

But if you aren't actually interested in querying posts and whole shebang the least involved way is to let WP come to 404 conclusion, then hook around `template_redirect` and depending on your own custom logic either let it proceed or cancel it out and perform necessary actions.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid by hooking earlier than after WP decides its should be a 404 page. I guess I will also have to hook around send_headers too then. Thanks a lot.